# Deserialize JSON element containing arbitrary names and datatypes

Tags: java, json, deserialization, gson

I have am trying to deseriliaze a JSON element where the element can contain 0 to many name/value pairs and 0 to many name/[] pairs. The values can be int, String, date, etc

An example element:

```
{"custom_fields":{ 
    "custom_label_36562": 25057, 
    "custom_label_36677": "some string",
    "custom_label_36566": [25085],
    "custom_label_36564": [25076,25077,28709,25078]   }}
```

What is the best approach to this? I tried parsing it into:

- `HashMap<String,List<<String>>`
- `HashMap<String,List`>`

but both times it just ends up null. I actually know the datatypes of each "custom label" so I just need to get the value into Java, and I can cast it later.

PS How do I enter a < sign without a space after it and not have all the text disappear?

Comment: Wrap text in `\`` to add code segments.

Comment: What JSON parser are you using?

Comment: Just tell the parser to parse it.  Don't tell it how.

Comment: I guess I can just deserialize it to an Object...

Answer (score 0):

Sooo no one answered this, I'm guessing I'll just desrialize it Object and take it from there...

Comment: Well, you probably can go with `HashMap<String,Object>`, or maybe `HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>`.

Comment: Well deserializing it to HashMap, HashMap<String,Object>, HashMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>> all result in the values being parsed to null. So I have to go with Object. This returns a StringMap object... I don't know whether it's going to be better to use this or to try to get GSON to parse into a JSON tree and go from there...

Comment: If it won't parse to `HashMap<String,Object>` then I suspect you're doing something wrong.  But of course in any case what you're getting is a "JSON tree".